# Text Editor Graphical Glitch on Xcode 6.4

Tags: xcode, text, graphics, editor

I'm experiencing a very odd graphical glitch with the code editor, initially I thought it was my machine's graphics going to pot but after further investigation it is definitely tied to Xcode and/or my project file.

This glitch appears to follow my project around, I have tried deleting derived data and userdata from the project folder, I've also made sure all of my fonts are the same (this was suggested in another thread for a similar sounding issue). Very often while editing code the below graphical error occurs, it is very frustrating. Has anyone else encountered this?

I've moved the project across multiple Macs and the problem persists, I would be really grateful for any insight on how to prevent this as I'm nearing the end of a *very* long project and this has pretty much put a halt to progress.

Thank you!

[Image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxKUf.png)

Comment: You might have better luck asking on the apple site, http://apple.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround that works for me until an official fix is provided. The glitch will still be happening but just during build and not while coding.
apple.stackexchange.com/a/202654